# Have I ruined my Arduino Nano with my terrible soldering (technique and tools!)

Tags: arduino-nano

So I bought a Arduino Nano and a *very* cheap soldering iron and solder from Alibaba. I was attempting to solder in some connections and failing pretty hard. A small resister popped off when trying to solder a wire to ground. I was pretty good when soldering in high school...but it's been a while since then.

By just plugging it into my computer, I was able to upload a simple program which switches the LED on and off - and that still works.

I'm not clearly not competent enough and I don't have a good enough soldering iron to do surface mount soldering to repair it. So I'm wondering if it'll still do what I want it to do.

My overall aim is to build a [simple music player](https://blog.arduino.cc/2020/08/01/juuke-is-an-arduino-powered-rfid-music-player-for-the-elderly/) for my 3 year old.

My question is, what does that resistor do? Have I ruined the board?

[image: Arduino Nano with missing resistor]

Comment: Is that the spot up near the top-right? What colour was the "resistor"? Brown? Judging by an image I found on the Internets it is actually the DTR reset capacitor, probably 0.1 µF.

Comment: You obviously solder without any solder flux. Learn for example from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqV2xU1fee8

Comment: @KIIV I can attest I soldered with solder. Lots of solder. 

What I did not do, was clean the board of residue and check for the correct technique for soldering wires to pinholes. I also used incredibly cheap soldering iron and solder from Alibaba. I've now rectified all those elements and am wondering whether I should just chuck the board or its still usable.

Comment: `I was able to upload a simple program which switches the LED on and off - and that still works` - sounds usable to me.

Comment: From what I can work out, the two reset pins are now dead. It looks like the other resister (capacitor?) was connected in series to the capacitor that was lost. I can't work out what else was connected to that...

Comment: @NickGammon I know it kinda works but with one tiny component missing, something is definitely broken. If I know what function doesn't work, then I know whether I can still do my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't answered either of my questions in the comments (where is the component?, what colour is it?) but judging by the position I think it is on the board it is the 0.1 µF capacitor which is part of the reset circuitry. It is designed to briefly pull /RESET low on power-up, or when DTR is asserted.

> If I know what function doesn't work, then I know whether I can still do my project.

Either the board works or it doesn't. There won't be "some function" that won't work. You may have problems resetting it but simply pressing the reset button on the other side (if there is one) should have the same effect.

I suggest you get a better soldering iron with a smaller tip. Also practice soldering a bit. The wire you show in the photo should have a blob of solder around it, not going "raw" into the hole as you have it. I also don't see how you can somehow unsolder a capacitor which is a couple of millimetres away from the pins on the edge of the board. Definitely more practice required.

A common technique with boards like the Nano is to solder a line of pins down each side like this:

[image: Nano underneath]

Then plug the whole thing into a breadboard and wire up your project on the breadboard. Then you don't need to worry about your soldering technique so much (once you have soldered on the pins, and you can get a friend to help you).

Comment: Thanks Nick for the comment. After a bit of practice and borrowing a different soldering iron, it turns out the issue was largely my cheap soldering iron. It was not getting up to temperature properly, so I was leaving it heating the joint for way too long before being able to melt the solder. I appreciate the help.